# Temporary tables in SnowFlake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am having a Job in Talend Open Studio like below

```
tDBInput --> tSnowFlakeOutput
```

When I am selecting the data from tDBInput and inserting in a table in tSnowFlakeOutput it is creating a temporary table like TABLENAME_yyyyMMdd_HHmm

Is there a way to insert in SnowFlake without using the temporary table, please help

Comment: This appears to be the way Talend works with Snowflake. If you search the Talend community forum this is discussed in detail